# Upgrading ASP.Net Core Web App (Angular) to 5

Tags: angular, visual-studio-2017

I use VS 2017 to create an ASP.Net Core Web App (template:Angular). The version of Angular in the generated project is 4.2.5. Using guide from https://angular-update-guide.firebaseapp.com/ I use the following command on PowerShell to upgrade Angular to 5.2.0.

```
npm install @angular/animations@'^5.2.0' @angular/common@'^5.2.0' @angular/compiler@'^5.2.0' @angular/compiler-cli@'^5.2.0' @angular/core@'^5.2.0' @angular/forms@'^5.2.0' @angular/http@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@'^5.2.0' @angular/platform-server@'^5.2.0' @angular/router@'^5.2.0' typescript@2.4.2 rxjs@'^5.5.2'
```

Now when I build and run the application, I get the following error in Startup.cs.

Version of @angular/compiler-cli needs to be 2.3.1 or greater. Current version is "5.2.0"

[image]
This error does not make sense. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are not having too much of code in your project already, the easiest path might be to create a new project with the correct dotnet template for SPA:

1. Make sure *** Microsoft.NET Core SDK 2.1.xxx**   - [rc | preview | beta] candidates are uninstalled. Those would create asp .net core 2.1 - [rc | preview | beta] applications.  **Microsoft.NET Core SDK 2.1.xxx ***
2. Follow the instructions [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa/index?view=aspnetcore-2.0#installation) to install the latest dotnet template
3. Execute a dotnet new angular
   Check the generated structure. package.json shall be under ClientApp folder and there would be a lot of references to Angular 5.2.0
4. For development purposes, make sure  that **ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development**
5. Everything else is pretty much the same:

   **dotnet restore**

   **dotnet run**